# Изменить элемент массива при его совпадении с другим

Tags: java, android

Подскажите пожалуйста, задача такая:
Есть динамический массив

```
ArrayList<String[]> myPoints;
```

В String[] координаты,
типа 59.9823482. Как пробежаться циклом по массиву, и если есть совпадение, то изменить элемент на + 0.0000001, но так, чтобы снова не совпадал с другими..

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < myPoints.size(); i++)
   while(checkValue(myPoints.get(i))
      myPoints.get(i) = Double.parseDouble(myPoints.get(i))+0.0000001;
```

**chekValue()**:

```
private boolean chekValue(String value)
   for(int i = 0; i < myPoints.size(); i++)
     if(myPoints.get(i).equals(value)) return true;
```

P.S. Если хочешь, можешь заменить это на стримы/foreach

Comment: окей. элемент 4 равен "10". элемент 7  равен "10". элемент 15 равен "10,000001". что тогда?

Comment: 1) сделай копию этого массива. 2) цикл внутри цикла, где ты будешь перебривать элементы этих массивов. 3) внутри этого сделай условие if где ты будешь сравнивать элементы из исходного массива с элементами из копии. 4) если находит совпадение изменяй значение (но только в одном массиве). p.s. все зависит от самой задачи. если тебе надо за каждый повтор увеличить значение - продолжай так. если "есть хотя бы 1 элемент - увеличить" - то можно прекращать цикл. и тд и тп

Comment: Ничего не понял.. Нужно чтобы небыло одинаковых координат, поэтому прибавляю 0.0000001.. Интересно как долго этот код работать будет, если 5000 строк проверять по двум координатам..